# ValidateSet values with spaces

Tags: powershell, validateset

Here's an example of `ValidateSet` where the values are strings which contain spaces:

```
function Test-ValidateSet
{ 
    param ([ValidateSet("abc def", "ghi jkl")][String]$Val) 

    $Val 
}
```

The IntelliSense works, however the completed value isn't quoted.

Is there a way to get the completed values to be quoted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Param ValidateSet values with Spaces and Tab completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633098/powershell-param-validateset-values-with-spaces-and-tab-completion)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug in PowerShell. I've filed it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/812233/auto-completed-values-with-spaces-do-not-have-quotes-around-them

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to quote yourself:

```
[ValidateSet("'abc def'", "'ghi jkl'")]
```

Though that looks silly if you intellisense after adding quotes in the command line:

```
Test-ValidateSet -Val ''ghi jkl''
```

DynamicParam doesn't work well with quoted values either.

Comment: I get an error when I try to use that.. The argument "abc def" does not belong to the set "'abc def'", "'ghi jkl'"